# basic_serial_port and async_read_until

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm trying to use a `boost::shared_ptr` with `async_read_until` and cannot get it to work.  This is my simplified code:

header

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::serial_port> serial_port_ptr;
serial_port_ptr serial_port;
boost::asio::streambuf response_data;
char delimiter = '\n';
boost::system::error_code error;
```

connect

```
serial_port = serial_port_ptr(new boost::asio::serial_port(io_service));
serial_port->open("/dev/ttyS0", error);
```

read

```
boost::asio::async_read_until(
  serial_port.get(), response_data, delimiter,
  boost::bind(
    &serial_comm::data_received,
      this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
  )
);
```

The error I get is `no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'`.  Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you try `*serial_port` instead of `serial_port.get()`?

Comment: @Xirema that worked!  brilliant!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've provided a pointer as the input to `boost::asio::async_read_until` instead of a reference. It should be rewritten like so:

```
boost::asio::async_read_until(
  *serial_port, response_data, delimiter,
  boost::bind(
    &serial_comm::data_received,
      this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
  )
);
```